# After Explode() geting result: %C4%84

Tags: php, unicode, explode

My problem is that after exploding a string I get this: %C4%84 value 
but I should get Ą. I can convert it using preg_replace, but is there simple way to convert ?

```
$band_song = explode('/',$url,6);
echo $band5=$band_song[3].' '.$band_song[4]);
```

Comment: Why `preg_replace()`? Your string is clearly [`URL encoded`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: and showing us the full string and code, would really help us give you the best answer

Comment: This is probaly caused by the fact it's not a regular A.

U+0104 Ą c4 84 Ą Ą LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH OGONEK

see this page: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=hex

Comment: Thanks Axiac. I was looking for this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply urlencode your variables.

```
$var = urlencode($original_var);
```

**EDIT**

You'd want decode, not encode sorry

```
$var = urldecode($original_var);
```